# how to store the result of working on input (R, Shiny, reactive)

Tags: r, shiny, system.reactive

I get input data from a file uploading widget (`reactive`) like:

**Step 1**    `getData <- reactive(...)  #psuedo code`.

And I need to do some work on the data and somehow store the result:

**Step 2**    `result #SOMEHOW# = Clean1(getData())   #psuedo code`.

In the end I'll render the result like:

**Step 3**    `output$DataAfter = renderTable({ result... })   #psuedo code`.

How should I do **Step 2**? I tried `result = reactive({ Clean1(getData()) })`, but there's an error: the input is `class NULL` before I upload the file.

---

**The following code works**, where I put the `Clean1()` function inside **Step 1** `getData()`

ui.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Uploading Files"),

    sidebarLayout(

        sidebarPanel(

            fileInput('file1', 'Choose CSV File',
                      accept=c('text/csv', 
                               'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 
                               '.csv')),

            tags$hr()

        ),
        mainPanel(
            tableOutput('DataBefore'),
            tableOutput('DataAfter'),
            tableOutput('Aggregation')
        )
    )
))
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)

library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(stringdist)
library(qdapRegex)
source('Clean1.R')

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    getData <- reactive({
        inFile <- input$file1
        if (is.null(inFile)) return(NULL)
        Clean1( read.csv(inFile$datapath) )

    })

    output$DataAfter = renderTable({
        as.data.frame( getData()[[1]] )

    })

    output$Aggregation = renderTable({
        as.data.frame( getData()[[2]] )

})

})
```

Clean1.R

```
Clean1 = function(data){

    data = data %>% sample_frac(1) 

    data = data %>%
        mutate_each(funs(toupper)) %>%    
        mutate_each(funs(gsub("[[:punct:]]", " ", .))) %>%
        mutate_each(funs(str_trim)) %>%
        mutate_each(funs(rm_white))

    by.town = data %>%
        group_by(State, Town) %>%
        summarise( Count = n() )

    return(list(data, by.town))
}
```

---

Now I **store the result like: `result = reactive({ Clean1(getData()) })`, and it shows error until I upload the file (still works in the end).

The error is

```
Don't know how to sample from objects of class NULL
```

This error should happen at the beginning of `Clean1()`. It seems to think `getData()` is `NULL` before I upload it.

ui. R and Clean1.R doesn't change.

server.R

```
library(shiny)

library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(stringdist)
library(qdapRegex)
source('Clean1.R')

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    getData <- reactive({
        inFile <- input$file1
        if (is.null(inFile)) return(NULL)
        read.csv(inFile$datapath)

    })

    result = reactive({
        Clean1(getData())
    })

    output$DataAfter = renderTable({
        as.data.frame( result()[[1]] )

    })

    output$Aggregation = renderTable({
        as.data.frame( result()[[2]] )

})

})
```

So what's standard way to do **Step 2**? Let me know please. Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is  `inFile$datapath`?

Comment: I don't quite understand the question.  Are you wanting it to not display an error at all?

Comment: The tag [system.reactive] is the Microsoft .NET namespace for the Reactive Framework. I don't think that applies here.

Comment: hi @user227710 I think that's how uploaded data is retrieved. I don't understand it at a lower level, just copied that code from the official  example. http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/file-upload.html

Answer (score 1):

The `getData()` is `NULL` when the code first evaluates, so that error makes sense.  You could make the `result` a reactive value that is monitored by an observer, but I think that would be more work than necessary.  If you want it to not display an error, try just wrapping the `Clean1` in a `tryCatch` block that returns `NULL` on error.

```
result = reactive({
    tryCatch({
        Clean1(getData())
    }, error=function(e) NULL)
})
```

Comment: hi @Legalizelt thanks for your help again! I revised the OP, hopefully it's clear now. I think the way you suggested will work, but I wonder there must be a standard way to do Step 2. Let me know what you think please. Thank you so much!

Comment: A simple test, !missing(getData()), should work as well.  Is there a reason to separate the result from getData() though?

Comment: Thanks @Legalizelt! Yes there is a reason. I omitted some code for clarity, but in fact I need to render 3 tables. Table 1 shows the input data, table 2 and 3 show the result after processing. So `getData()` and `result` need to be stored separately.

Comment: Well, for lack of a better idea, I would use the !missing test, but I don't know what would be considered standard.

Comment: thanks a lot @Legalizelt   I used `if( !is.null(getData()) ){ Cean1(getData()) }` and it's working now. `if( !missing(getData()) )` seems to not work, giving an error `invalid use of 'missing'`? Did I write the syntax wrong?

Comment: No, sorry I wasn't testing that.  The missing is for missing arguments, yours is right